# Building docker images in Gitlab CI and pushing to AWS ECR.

Tags: continuous-integration, docker, aws, gitlab

I want to do something fairly simply in my Gitlab CI pipeline - I want to build the docker image and push it to an AWS ECR repo.

I've looked at [this Gitlab CI guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) and one of the suggestions it makes is using the `docker:latest` image.

However, in order to access the AWS ECR repo - I'm also going to need to AWS commands - as from what I can see [AWS only allows 12 hour tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html) for accessing ECR repos.

I've searched docker hub and I can't find any public images that have both docker-in-docker and AWS cli. This is odd - because I imagine this is a very common solution.

Can someone suggest is there another standard way people build and push images to AWS ECR from Gitlab CI?

Comment: any good reason for using AWS ECR over a private docker registry?
with private docker registry you got all the control and flexibility you need, and not bound by AWS tools (and prices...)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best but still an option to consider. 
Install aws cli dynamically during the build, and possibly save as cached artifact/dependency.
`pip install awscli --upgrade --user`